# What's the best way to update an image in my tableview image subview?

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, subview

Specifically, how do you get the image subview from a uitableview cell?

My table view gets data from the web asynchronously. When I created the image view the first time, I added the view by:

```
[imageView setImage:image];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

After new data is retrieved, I call `reloadData` to refresh the table view. But to update the image, I'd like to get a handle of this imageView (if it exist) and update the image.

My question is: Given the cell, is there a way to get this image view (handle) directly , or do I have to loop through the subviews to find the specific image view?

Any answer is highly appreciated!

Lu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a tag on the imageView when you create it:

```
 [image viewSetTag: uniqueIntValue];
```

Then when you want to grab the view use:

```
UIView* recoveredImageView = [cell viewWithTag uniqueIntValue];
```

Comment: Great! I will give it a try. Thanks, Matthew, for the quick reply!