# Duplicated text in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I got an iOS app with table view. When i select rows several times, information in selected one duplicate.

You can see it on a picture:
[image]

I add cell's in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    Place *item = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PermianSansTypeface" size:15.0]];
    label.text =item.name;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 35);
    [cell addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    OnePlaceViewController *placeView = [[OnePlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OnePlaceViewController" bundle:nil];
    placeView.nom = indexPath.row;
    placeView.source = source;
    placeView.route = route;
    placeView.titleView = titleView;
    /*
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selected = NO;
    */
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:placeView animated:YES];
}
```

Why do information duplicate? Thnx.

Comment: I left my crystal ball at home, so you'll have to post some code.

Comment: i add some code. look at it please

Comment: @EvanMulawski lol...but on first guess, it seems to be an issue with cell reuse. Both `cellForRowAtIndex` and `didSelectRowAtIndex` would be required for a better answer.

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov: We need to see `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, too.

Comment: i did it =) but i dont think that the problem here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're adding `UILabel` as subView everytime. Since cells are reused, everytime the table reloads, multiple `UILabel`s are added. So, my suggestion would be to go through all the subviews of the cell and remove them before adding new label.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
Place *item = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PermianSansTypeface" size:15.0]];
label.text =item.name;
label.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 35);
for(UIView *v in [cell subviews])
{
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
       [v removeFromSuperview];
}
[cell addSubview:label];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: really, you should accept my answer. Thats a much cleaner approach. You don't need to add, remove and recreate the labels all the time. Also you DONT have to go through all subviews. My solution is less memory intense and faster. But choose yourself.

Comment: @jaydee3 There's no doubt your approach is much cleaner and efficient than mine but I think he asked for the why part, not the how!

Comment: no offense, but SO is a knowledge base and should always give the best possible answer. the answer is not only for him.

Comment: None taken man...but the how part has already been answered multiple times on [SO itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299391/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-image-in-my-tableview-image-subview). I'm not saying your answer is not novel, just that you missed that little reason that was specifically asked for in the question for this special case. But then I'm not the one to judge! You should address your issue to the asker.

Answer (score 8):

you're adding a label EVERYTIME.. change it like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    Place *item = [source objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PermianSansTypeface" size:15.0]];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 35);
    label.tag = 666;
    [cell addSubview:label];
    // add this unless you're using ARC
    // [label release];
    // [cell autorelease];
  }

  UILabel* cellLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag: 666];
  cellLabel.text = item.name;

  return cell;
}
```