# How to achieve flip animation and change my UIImage inside UITableView cell?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uianimation

I have UITableView and cell's are customized and have a UIImage with UIbutton, UIlabel and another UIbutton. When user clicks the UIImage i want this image to flip and display another image here. The flip should be an animation excatly same as the FlipSide template.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the built-in animations for the same:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:cell cache:YES];
[oldImageView removeFromSuperview];
[cell addSubview:newImageView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Of course, your cell and imageViews would have to be created/referenced before-hand. I haven't tried this myself but it should do the trick.

Comment: SO i can make image available throughout the class but are you saying that i should make the cell define for the whole class. Because by default we create the cell in TableView delegate method and release it there.

Comment: No no, don't keep reference with names, but with tags as [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299391/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-image-in-my-tableview-image-subview).